# Общие куки для всех браузеров selenium

Tags: java, сессия, selenium

Я создаю браузер, в котором логинюсь на сайте и считываю ссылки, для каждой ссылки мне нужно создать еще один браузер и при этом чтобы куки первого браузера распространялись и на второй.

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Добавление куков первого браузера ко второму работает некорректно, при передаче определенных куков кидает ошибку.

```
driver.manage().getCookies().forEach(c -> driver2.manage.addCookie(c));
```

Как селениуму дать понять, что он должен использовать общий файл с куками (или где они хранятся)? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Пример ответа уже существует в [англоязычном](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118048/selenium-firefoxdriver-share-session-cookies-between-different-instances%20%22%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC) SO:

```
var driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.html-kit.com/tools/cookietester/");
driver1.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value=\"Set Test Cookie\"]").Click();

var driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
driver2.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.html-kit.com/tools/cookietester/");

// Copy cookies from one driver to the other
foreach (Cookie c in driver1.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies)
{
driver2.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie(c.Name, c.Value,   c.Domain.TrimStart('.'), c.Path, c.Expiry));
}

driver2.Navigate().Refresh();
```

Как там сказано, проблема с cookies может быть только если ваши драйверах идут на другие домены, и в этом случае такие шаги помогут вам скопировать cookies правильно:

Driver1: Navigate to SiteA
Driver1: Login
Driver2: Navigate to SiteA
Copy cookies from Driver1 to Driver2
Driver2: Refresh (Should be logged in now)
Driver2: Navigate to SiteB

Comment: Таким образом все равно не все куки передаются.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему иначе, создал профиль в Firefox, в котором залогинился на нужном сайте и для каждого объекта FirefoxDriver использую этот профиль.